# Radeon HD 6850 Incorrect Graphics Drivers? Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

This all started when the ubuntu update center said my computer needed updates. I agreed, and when the updates were finished it required a reboot. Upon rebooting I tried logging in, and when
I saw the desktop there was no toolbar or launcher. I googled it a bit, and found a tutorial similar to this: http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html Little did I know, these drivers were for Radeon HD 2xxx-4xxx series. I followed the tutorial and then rebooted. After rebooting it came up with a screen that says "The system is running in low graphics mode" I tried some tutorials here: [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) but to no avail. After booting into  Every command I try I always tells me to run 'apt-get -f install' Every time I try this command I get: 'Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-legacy_2%3a8.97.100.7-makson~ppa1_amd64.deb'
'E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'

P.S. I am very new to Ubuntu, and linux. I have mostly used windows. I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

Installation of AMD Catalyst (Radeon HD Driver) is complicated in Ubuntu. This link maybe help you: [askubuntu-What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

Comment: on the Installer, when I try the first option it tells me what OS i'm running and then if I try to continue it says operation aborted. The second option ask me which path to install it in. I tried in the home folder, it installed normally. When rebooting I still booted into Low graphics mode. Oh I should add that I had used ctrl + alt + F1 to get to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-legacy_2%3a8.97.100.7-makson~ppa1_amd64.deb'
>   'E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

You have enabled a PPA and there is a problem with the package install script. Try as the page suggests:

> If something goes wrong, you can purge the packages by running
>   following commands:
>
> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge sudo ppa-purge ppa:makson96/fglrx

Or just install Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu 12.10 is over 18 months old now and unsupported, there have been a lot of updates to the open source driver since then, and your card should work well without any messing around.

edit: Just realised this is an old question...